# What is this data ... where trying to accomplish? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

In the random-fu package, there is this `data` declaration:

```
data Multinomial p a where
    Multinomial :: [p] -> a -> Multinomial p [a]
```

I understand that this is a GADT, but what is it trying to accomplish? Is it placing restrictions on `p` or `a`, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It changes the return type of the constructor. If it was defined like this

```
data Multinomial p a = Multinomial [p] a
```

our constructor would have the type

```
Multinomial :: [p] -> a -> Multinomial p a
```

The GADT changes the second type argument in the result type of the constructor to `[a]`.

Comment: Thanks, but why does the author do this? What's the benefit of having it be `[a]` instead of `a`?

Comment: @yong Most likely the author wants to store more than one value of `a` in list.

Answer (score 5):

As for the "why", the `Distribution` type-class defines `rvar` as

```
class Distribution d t where
    rvar :: d t -> RVar t
```

So the type parameter of the given distribution determines the type of the samples you get out of the `RVar`. So using the GADT, the `Multinomial` distribution is defined as one that always returns multiple values per sample even though it's constructed with just a single value of `a`.